# Flash notices working in all browsers except IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap style flash messages to display errors to the user. They seem to work in all browsers except for IE. When I view the source, the html for the message is not being produced.

```
<% flash.each do | name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") if name.to_s == 'error' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if this is related, but storing session variables is not working either in IE.

Comment: Which IE version? Is it supported by bootstrap? Do you have extra styles on your software? This should be related with the CSS of your div tag. If you can see it on ie when clicking in "show source code", you can have sure of it.

Comment: IE10. The message div and it's contents are not showing in the source only in IE.